# error: cannot find symbol variable activity_main

Tags: java, android, debugging, symbols

I'm an android novice. I'm trying to do some practice work but I am getting these two errors that I've tried for hours to fix

error: cannot find symbol variable activity_main

error: cannot find symbol variable tabLayout

Below is my MainActivity.java then after that the activity_main.xml

```
package com.example.rawtablayoutdemo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

import android.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TabLayout tabLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
}
```

}

this is the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[My screen that shows me the two errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNc2v.png)

I'm sure you deep masters of code know the solution for my simple question born from a lack of understanding of Android Studio and making android apps. Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the import statement `import android.R`. Most probably it will work, if it doesn't try clearing and rebuilding the project from the Build -> Clean Project, then Build -> Rebuild Project.

Comment: Thanks you for your assistance great coder Akshat. That got rid of the first error but I still have the second error which is "error: cannot find symbol variable tabLayout"   do you know how to get rid of that as well sir?

Comment: Check your dependencies...Does your dependencies included design library/material theme library ?

Comment: By dependencies do you mean import statements? How do I check my dependencies?

Comment: No actual dependency in build.gradle